# Pergunta com Avaliação Positiva, Resposta considerada válida mas com avaliação negativa

Tags: debate, resposta-aceita, respostas-erradas

Acabo de ver uma situação muito estranha [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12795/aumentar-quantidade-de-linhas-retornadas-por-select-group-no-mysql), a pergunta tem avaliação +3, a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12797/7210) com visto do autor que resolveu o problema tem -8 e por fim [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12838/7210) que fala noutro assunto que nada tem a ver com a pergunta (MySQL Workbench) tem +8. Muito estranho, nunca tinha visto.

A pergunta que fica da minha parte é o que se pode fazer com essa pergunta? Apagar? Fechar? Fazer a pergunta de novo? Outra coisa?

Comment: A resposta com -8 tinha -4 no momento em que foi atualizada (ver http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/12795/timeline). Os outros votos contra vieram mais tarde.

Comment: Mas o que está causando o problema é o workbench OU ferramenta similar. Como mencionei no comment, o MySQL por si só não tem esse limite de 1000 rows. Se eu fosse responder, mencionaria "alguma ferramenta", não especificamente o WB, mas como o user em questão disse "provavelmente" em vez de afirmar certeza absoluta, levou o meu +1. Quanto ao que fazer, nao tenho nada a comentar (por isso só pus comment e não resposta). ADENDO: accept é a opinião do autor, voto é opinião da comunidade. É normal haver discrepância (nesse caso, um pouco acima do normal, concordo).

Comment: @Bacco Mesmo assim o autor nunca mencionou o WB, seria mesmo esse o problema? É que basear respostas no "Você provavelmente está usando MySQL Workbench" acho que é um bocado mau. Apesar de poder ser, parece-me que a resposta com mais avaliação positiva poderá nem ser a correta. Consoante a pergunta deveria ter a resposta que mais se adequa. De qualquer forma acho que tens razão na parte da separação do accept e voto, são coisas diferentes.

Comment: De qualquer forma deve ser muito confuso para quem vê, eu fiquei pelo menos. Imagino que futuras visitas a pergunta vai acontecer o mesmo.

Comment: Pode ser mesmo que alguns dos votos contra tenham sido influenciados por outras atitudes do usuário. E pode ser que alguns tenham sido por causa da atitude dele nessa pergunta mesmo, já que ele tentou salvar a resposta repetindo o que já estava dito na outra resposta. Seja como for, não há muito o que fazer, as pessoas têm o direito de votar como bem entenderem. Se achar que houve abuso, sinalize a resposta e peça para o moderador apurar o ocorrido.

Comment: Ok entendo, obrigado pela resposta @bfavaretto.